# Run an airflow dag from a specific task

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow

I have an airflow dag running every 15 mins. This dag has 3 tasks
TaskA
TaskB
TaskC
I want to write a logic in such a way that if for a dag run TaskB fails, then in next run Dag should start from failed task only(from TaskB).

Im looking for a solution where the dag runs from the failed tasks and skips the tasks which were in success in previous run.